# PHP reports incorrect MIME type

Tags: php, mime-types, mime

I am designing a simple PHP script to allow uploads of *.cpp source files. As a basic security measure, I check the MIME type of the temporary file before moving it to a permanent location. When I run `file --mime myfile.cpp` in Terminal (on Mac OS X) it shows up as `text/x-c`. Yet the server sees it as a `application/octet-stream` for some reason. In `/etc/mime.types` the "cpp" extension is there under `text/x-c++src` which leads me to believe it's an issue with MIME types on Mac.

I've tried the same procedure from Ubuntu and it works fine (it shows up as `text/x-c++src`). I am using Chrome on both computers.

It's not exactly a programming question per se, but there may be some PHP trick to this that I'm not familiar with.

```
$temp_file=$_FILES["file"]["type"];
if(($temp_file!="text/x-c++src")||($temp_file!="text/x-c")) {
    echo "<p style=\"color:red;font-style:italic\">Please upload a valid C++ file.</p>";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `$_FILES['userfile']['type']` contains the mime-type which the browser sent (during the upload). You can use it, but you cannot trust it.

Try getting the mime-type from `$_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']` using:

```
$mime = mime_content_type($tmp_name);
// or, as this is deprecated:
$info = new finfo(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
$mime = $info->file($tmp_name);
```

Or, you can guess by the original file-name's extension in `strrchr($_FILES['userfile']['name'], '.')`.

Comment: I don't want to use the uploaded file's extension because that is extremely easy to spoof. I'll check out the finfo() method though, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The server sees whatever type the browser that uploaded it says it is.

Browsers aren't very good at determining file types in general, and malicious uploaders can always override it.

You can't trust the mime type. If you want to reasonably reliably know what type of file it is, you have to use a utility like `file` to sniff the data.