# Check JSON file when uploading

Tags: php, json, file-upload

I am creating upload function where i want to upload a JSON file.

my JSON string inside the file is :`{"name":"John"}`

my PHP code:

```
$fileType = $_FILES['uploaded']['type'];
if ($fileType != "application/json") {
  print 'Not valid JSON file';
}
```

also tried:

```
$fileType = $_FILES['uploaded']['type'];
if ($fileType != "text/json") {
  print 'Not valid JSON file';
}
```

when i am trying to upload JSON file it shows me the 'Not valid JSON file' error.

plz help me what is wrong with this code.

Comment: Well, what is the mimetype?

Comment: what you want to achieve?

Comment: @Blender i don't know, currently i am working on a local server.

Comment: @Fasilkk i want to upload a JSON file to server, but before that i want to check whether the JSON file is valid or not.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP reports incorrect MIME type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13389288/php-reports-incorrect-mime-type)

Answer (score 2):

There is no explicit file type set when creating *.json files. Instead the files mime-type is going to be `application/octet-stream`, which is a binary file, typically an application or document that has to be opened in an application.

Check your array `$_FILES['uploaded']` for the type.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as "application/json". After uploading read the whole file into string using file_get_contents() [http://pl1.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php] and use json_decode() [http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php], which will return null if it wasn't a real json.

```
$content = file_get_contents($filePath);
$json = json_decode($content, true);
if($json === null) print('Its not a Json! Its a Jacob:P')
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is nice and simple PHP script to Check JSON file while uploading:

```php
    // Set maximum file size in bytes
    $max_file_size = 1048576; // 1 MB
    
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
      // Check if the file was uploaded successfully
      if (isset($_FILES['json_file']['error']) && $_FILES['json_file']['error'] === UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
        // Get the file information
        $file = $_FILES['json_file'];
    
        // Check if the file type is JSON
        if ($file['type'] === 'application/json') {
          // Check if the file size is less than the maximum file size
          if ($file['size'] <= $max_file_size) {
            // Read the file content
            $file_content = file_get_contents($file['tmp_name']);
    
            // Check if the file content is valid JSON
            if (json_decode($file_content) !== null) {
              // Move the uploaded file to the desired directory
              move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'], '/path/to/directory/' . $file['name']);
    
              // Return success message
              echo 'The file was uploaded successfully.';
            } else {
              // Return error message
              echo 'The file is not a valid JSON file.';
            }
          } else {
            // Return error message
            echo 'The file size exceeds the maximum allowed file size.';
          }
        } else {
          // Return error message
          echo 'The file is not a JSON file.';
        }
      } else {
        // Return error message
        echo 'There was an error uploading the file.';
      }
    }
```